# Parse JSON data from URL in ASP.NET Core MVC using C# doesn't work

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc, json-deserialization, dynamic-tables

I tried to follow this tutorial:

https://fullstackdotnetcoder.blogspot.com/p/how-to-read-parse-json-data-from-url-in.html

but I don't know enough about ASP.NET MVC and Json.NET to figure out what I do wrong or what I also need to do. Please help me so I can understand it better.

I get this error in Visual Studio:

Error:CS1061|File:objJson.cs|Line:16|'object' does not contain a definition for 'DeserializeObject' and no accessible extension method 'DeserializeObject' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is my class for the Json structure (`RootObject.cs`):

```
namespace ProjectDemoJsonURL.Models.JsonModel
{
    public class RootObject
    {
        public int userId { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public bool completed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The controller (`objJson.cs`)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;

namespace ProjectDemoJsonURL.Models.JsonModel
{
    public class objJson : Controller
    {
        public object Converter { get; private set; }

        public ActionResult GetJsonDataModel()
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "cookievalue");
            var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
            Models.JsonModel.RootObject objJson = Converter.DeserializeObject<Models.JsonModel.RootObject>(json);

            return View(objJson);
        }
    }
}
```

The view to show Json output which I created with right click on `GetJsonDataModel()` (`index.cshtml`):

```
@model ProjectDemoJsonURL.Models.JsonModel.RootObject
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetJsonDataModel";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>GetJsonDataModel</h2>
@{ 
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>userId</th>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>completed</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>@Model.userId</th>
        <th>@Model.id</th>
        <th>@Model.title</th>
        <th>@Model.completed</th>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

I followed this tutorial to have a working ASP.NET Core project where I can see how it works and try different things.

Comment: This question deals with namespaces and potentially assembly references. But on your RootObject class, you haven't shown us what namespace it's in. Please share that with us. And please remove your JsonConvert object - you'll be accessing a static method from Newtonsoft's JsonConvert class, so having a property with the same name is going to confuse everything.

Comment: In my RootObject class I had no namespace and adding one solved 5/6 errors..

Comment: So, what errors do you still have?

Comment: Error:CS1061|File:objJson.cs|Line:16|'object' does not contain a definition for 'DeserializeObject' and no accessible extension method 'DeserializeObject' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Your compilation issue is because your property `Converter` is defined as `object`, but I'm guessing it's supposed to be a `JsonConverter` of some kind. (It's not in the tutorial, and you're not actually setting its value, so I'm wondering if it's an error?)

Comment: My suggestion: rename the `Converter` back to `JsonConvert` in line 16, and delete the definition of `Converter`. You don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Models.JsonModel.RootObject objJson = Converter.DeserializeObject<Models.JsonModel.RootObject>(json);
```

back to

```
Models.JsonModel.RootObject objJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.JsonModel.RootObject>(json);
```

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` is a static method, so you don't need to have a class instance present: you can call it directly from the type.

Then, delete your definition of `Converter` from earlier in the controller. You don't need it for this scenario, and you weren't setting it to a value, anyway.

Comment: Thank you that solved the Error, now I wanted to navigate with the navbar to the Razor Page that displays the Json-Data. I wrote this `<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="objJson" asp-action="Table">Tabelle</a> </li>` in _Layout.cshtml and then I tried to navigate to this site but my browser says localhost-site not found. Is this happening because the standard Razor-Page and the page that I created are in different folders? (Views\Home\Index and Views\objJson\Table)

Comment: You need to add an action which route is `\objJson\Table` ,and then return a view in it.

Comment: If my answer helped you solve the error, please mark it as your accepted answer. It would be best if you put your additional question in a new site post. (I see that @YiyiYou has already posted an answer, which is probably correct.)